# how to play PCM sound file in Ubuntu?

Tags: linux, pcm

I have a PCM sound file with sample rate 16000, sample bit 16 and channel 1. I want to play it , but there's no software can do. I also tried ffplay like :

```
ffplay -ar 16000 -ac 1 snake.raw
```

But still failed. How to play the PCM sound file in Ubuntu?

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/76665/playing-a-pcm-file-on-a-unix-system

Answer (score 42):

To use `ffplay` with signed 16-bit little endian raw PCM, specify `-f s16le`:

```
ffplay -f s16le -ar 16k -ac 1 snake.raw
```

For a stereo, 32-bit floating-point, little endian, 48 kHz file specify:

```
ffplay -f f32le -ar 48k -ac 2 snake.raw
```

For a list of supported formats for the `-f` option, use `ffplay -formats`.  `-ar` is the sample rate and `-ac` is the number of channels.

Comment: Thank you, in my case it was: `ffplay -f s32be -ar 22222 -ac 2` (big endian with often used   22222Hz)

Answer (score 30):

You can use `play`/`sox`, which should be standard in ubuntu

```
play -t raw -r 16k -e signed -b 16 -c 1 snake.raw 

-r = sampling rate
-b = sampling precision (bits)
-c = number of channels
```

Comment: `--endian` is also interesting.